# Sending Auto Mails for new posts from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

How can I send email to a specific mail address automatically whenever a new posts  has been publish to wordpress? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plugin for this activity to perform.
for that you can use [Subscriber](http://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe2) plugin.

**OR**

You can add this code into your `functions.php` file

```
function email_members($post_ID)  {
    global $wpdb;
    $usersarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users;");    
    $users = implode(",", $usersarray);
    mail($users, "New WordPress post!", 'A new post have been published on site name');
    return $post_ID;
}

   add_action('publish_post', 'email_members');
```